# Identifing city (and buildings) below Mount Fuji

Tags: identify-this, architecture, cities, landmarks, mount-fuji

I have just received a paper folder for some documents, which has this beautiful photo in the back:

[image]

I assume, this is [Mount Fuji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Fuji). Can you help me identify city, that lays below (and it is pictured here), plus these four building marked on the photo?

Comment: [**This photo**](http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg) from [this page](http://www.japaneseammo.com/100-reasons-why-you-should-visit-japan-japan-is-awesome/)  at 6000 x 4004 is a, but not THE motherlode. It was taken at almost exactly the same spot but can be seen to differ somewhat. However, as a "wander around the scene" resource it's superb. It benefits from slight colour adjustment and a degree of sharpening top maximise details. [Mountain looks suspiciously like the mountain in 'The last Samurai' (which it's NOT :-) )]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The city is Fujiyoshida on the NNE side of Mt Fuji. See jpatokal's answer for the exact camera location.

From left to right, the marked buildings are:

1. [Fujisan station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujisan_Station). The glass facade that's visible from street level is quite poorly defined in this photo, but covers the bottom third of the blue frame. The lighter part that's visible in the photo sticks up *above* the roof of the glass-covered main part. On some of the Google Street View photos taken nearby one can glimpse the red logo-like decoration that's visible at the left end on the building in this picture.
2. Not a building but a group of tall trees [here on Google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.48496,138.79465&ll=35.486688,138.795535&spn=0.002289,0.00327&num=1&t=k&z=19&output=classic); behind the trees one sees the sunlit east facade of the [Fujiyoshida City Hotel](http://www.thebesthotels.org/room-photo-fuji-yoshida-city-hotel-ID679013.htm).
3. The Fujigoko Cultural Center, [here on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=35.491512,138.796417&spn=0.002289,0.00327&t=h&z=19&output=classic).
4. The high school [here](https://maps.google.com/maps?ll=35.482193,138.790034&spn=0.002298,0.00327&t=k&z=19&output=classic).

Russell McMahon found a [much more detailed photo](http://www.japaneseammo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/bigstock-Mt-Fuji-with-fall-colors-in-j-48491102.jpg) taken at almost exactly the same spot (just a few meters left) and time of day, which clearly confirms these identifications.

Comment: Oh! I assumed, as the OP I guess, that the trees were hiding a building! Nice trees, btw: http://goo.gl/maps/lr1BW

Comment: Thanks for these explanation. Unfortunately the "much more detailed photo" link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

The photo is taken from the grounds of [Arakura Sengen Shrine](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/LocationPhotoDirectLink-g1165976-d1368665-i118158782-Kawaguchi_Sengen_Shrine-Fujikawaguchiko_machi_Minamitsuru_gun_Yamanashi.html#118158782) in **[Fuji-Kawaguchiko, Yamanashi, Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawaguchiko,_Yamanashi)**, and appears to be a crop of [this image](http://www.jetlinecruise.com/images/small-banner/Mount-Fuji-Japan.jpg) (not the original either, though).

The rightmost building appears to be [the town hall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fujikawaguchiko,_Yamanashi#/media/File:Fujikawaguchiko-town-office.JPG).  Not sure about the rest, but there are a bunch of large hotels and the [Fuji-Q amusement park](http://www.fujiq.jp/) nearby that seem like likely candidates.

Comment: this is the most complete (and highest resolution) version I can find: http://travels.kilroy.net/media/5107635/japan-mount-fuji.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The bottommost building is labeled as 富士五湖文化センター ([Fujigoko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuji_Five_Lakes) Cultural Center) on Google Maps.

However, the official website of that cultural center http://www.mfi.or.jp/fcpa/access.htm tells us that the biggest building (which is probably the one you are interested in) is called ふじさんホール (Fujisan Hall).

The same complex also hosts a city meeting hall and a library, conveniently referred to as 富士吉田市民会館 and 富士吉田市民図書館 respectively.