# Identifing building in Lancaster

Tags: uk, identify-this, cities

Can someone identify this building for me and possibly write me anything about it?

[image]

I only know, that it is located in Lancaster.

Comment: how do you know that? Is the picture from a web page? Do you have an address?

Comment: Without knowing anything at all about it, I can tell you it's an old cotton mill. There are thousands of them all over the north of England.

Comment: @KateGregory Nope. It is an image from my collection and file is titled just `Lancaster.jpg`. It comes from [FreeImages.co.uk](http://www.FreeImages.co.uk) site and I have found [a copy of it](http://valuestockphoto.com/stockimages/Architecture/Urban/lancaster_warehouse1000407.jpg.html) in valuestockphoto.com.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is there anything specific about the mill that says "cotton" as opposed to, say, wool or wagons or beer or what have you?

Comment: Unfortunately the Google aerial photos of Lancaster seem to be rather low-resolution.  But the fact that the street is at least 3-4 lanes may be helpful - Lancaster doesn't seem to have very many streets that wide.

Comment: You really haven't explained why you think it's in Lancaster, apart from that being the file name. I'm also beginning to wonder how this is related to travel.

Comment: @DJClayworth (1) Because I don't have any other arguments _except_ filename. (2) I thought that [tag:identify-this] questions are allowed here for just identifying pictured places _without_ any relation to travel and are on-topic here. I have [another](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44719/15281) question of this kind, well received by the community, even though I don't plan to visit Mt. Fuji soon and even though identifying city below Mt. Fuji also hasn't much in relation with travelling.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It certainly doesn't, and those that do rarely have old mills on them. Unfortunately double yellow lines are invariably at the edge of the road,so this must be an ordinary street with a deceptive camera angle.

Comment: @TimLymington: Oops.  I was thinking of US conventions, in which a double yellow line would be in the middle of the road (separating two directions of traffic).

Comment: The double yellow lines on the edge of the road would tend to confirm a British location, and the cars look British enough: but at the left hand side there are some high-looking snow-capped mountains which to me would not be compatible with Lancaster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is the building: [Google Maps street view link](https://www.google.com/maps/@54.048585,-2.795148,3a,75y,148.57h,88.32t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1swyaeBdxdyl5tmQgGgtSgTw!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1?hl=en)

[image]

Comment: They must have gotten a heritage exclusion for the Sycamore tree.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure if they own the building, but the image appears on http://www.cassandra-fp7.eu/page/Workshop_home (on the first section of their slideshow), this could though be beacuse it is a stock image.

Comment: I think that's just a stock photo.  I can't find any reference on that site to anything to do with Lancaster, and [neither can Google](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=lancaster+site:cassandra-fp7.eu).  The site seems to be run by an institute in Greece.