# How to travel to this tower with a gorgeous view toward Mount Fuji?

Tags: trains, japan, identify-this, tokyo, mount-fuji

I would like to visit this place.

1. What is the name of this tower? The location of the town/city of this tower? And what is the relative direction of this tower to Fuji mountain?
2. What is the recommended way to visit this tower by traveling by bus or train from the Tokyo Station (東京駅)?

[image: view of Mount Fuji with a tower in the foreground]

Answer (score 52):

This is the **Chureito Pagoda** (忠霊塔) on the grounds of Arakura Sengen Shrine near Fujiyoshida, some 10-odd km northwest of Mt Fuji.  It's about a 10 min walk from Shimo-Yoshida Station on the Fuji-Kyuko line, reachable in about 2.5 hours by train from Shinjuku in Tokyo with a transfer at Otsuki:

https://maps.app.goo.gl/uiFYVrUa41rqVVkQ8

Note that this view is possible only on a clear spring day during cherry blossom season around mid-April, and Fuji is a notoriously "shy" mountain often covered in clouds, so there are only a few days per year when you can pull off a shot like this.  It's also a *very* well known spot for this, so on those days expect to share the temple with a few thousand Instagram influencers all gunning for it as well.

Random fun fact: this is (at least) [the 2nd question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44719/identifing-city-and-buildings-below-mount-fuji) we've had so far about the same place!

Answer (score 18):

> The Chureito Pagoda (忠霊塔, Chūreitō) is a five storied pagoda on the
> mountainside overlooking Fujiyoshida City and Mount Fuji off in the
> distance. The pagoda is part of the Arakura Sengen Shrine and was
> built as a peace memorial in 1963 nearly 400 steps up the mountain
> from the shrine's main buildings.

From https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e6917.html

I downloaded the image, went to https://images.Google.com, clicked the camera icon, and uploaded the image.  Above was the first result.  Second was https://www.jrailpass.com/blog/chureito-pagoda-travel-guide